# How do I change state of MUI Data Grid when using a checkbox in cellRender?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So I have a fairly simple scenario I'm working with where I need a checkbox in a MUI data grid, but not using checkboxSelection. It's easy enough for me to render my checkbox in a column, but I can't really figure out how to change the state of that grid row once I check the box. The function receives the event object and you can access the target element, but I'm trying to actually change the value of the confirmed property on the row.

Here's the sample code for the component.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Checkbox } from '@mui/material';
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid'

const DataTable = () => {

    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([])

    function handleConfirmChange() {
      console.log('How do I change row state here????');
    }

    const columns = [
      { field: 'title', headerName: 'Title', width: 200 },
      { field: 'body', headerName: 'Body', width: 600 },
      {
        field: 'confirmed',
        headerName: 'Confirmed',
        renderCell: (params) => (
          <Checkbox
            checked={params.confirmed===1}
            onChange={handleConfirmChange}
          />
        ),
      }
    ]

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
          .then((data) => data.json())
          .then((data) => {
            for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
              data[i].confirmed = false;
            }
            setTableData(data);
          })
    
      }, [])

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 700, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={tableData}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={12}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default DataTable
```

Comment: It is now explained in the docs https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-definition/#using-hooks-inside-a-renderer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `checked={params.confirmed===1}` statement, the `confirmed` in the `params` property is not the property from the `tableData`. It is the columns' field name.

To get the clicked row, we have to set Id for each row, pass the `rowId` as param from the `checkbox`, then we can identify the clicked row.

So, in the `useEffect` hook, we have to set the `rowId` based on the index.

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setTableData(
          data.map((x, index) => ({
            ...x,
            rowId: index,
            confirmed: false
          }))
        );
      });
  }, []);
```

Then pass the `row` as param in the checkbox click event. Also, set the `checked` property as `params.rows?.confirmed`. The `params.rows` gives the actual row data. The rows maybe null during the initialization, so we have to set  [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to the `confirmed` property.

```
 <Checkbox
   checked={params.rows?.confirmed}
   onChange={() => handleConfirmChange(params.row)}
 />
```

In the `handleConfirmChange` function, get the clicked row and update the `confirmed` property. Loop through the `tableData` array and get the clicked row, then set the `confirmed` and update the grid.

```
function handleConfirmChange(clickedRow) {
const updatedData = tableData.map((x) => {
  if (x.rowId === clickedRow.rowId) {
    return {
      ...x,
      confirmed: !clickedRow.confirmed
    };
  }
  return x;
});
setTableData(updatedData);
```

}

Here is the updated working code and codesandbox.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Checkbox } from "@mui/material";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

export default function DataTable() {
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);

  function handleConfirmChange(clickedRow) {
    const updatedData = tableData.map((x) => {
      if (x.rowId === clickedRow) {
        return {
          ...x,
          confirmed: true
        };
      }
      return x;
    });
    setTableData(updatedData);
  }

  const columns = [
    { field: "title", headerName: "Title", width: 200 },
    { field: "body", headerName: "Body", width: 400 },
    {
      field: "confirmed",
      headerName: "Confirmed",
      renderCell: (params) => (
        <Checkbox
          checked={params.rows?.confirmed}
          onChange={() => handleConfirmChange(params.row.rowId)}
        />
      )
    }
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setTableData(
          data.map((x, index) => ({
            ...x,
            rowId: index,
            confirmed: false
          }))
        );
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={tableData}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={12}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[12]}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit SOQ-71445011-MUI-DataGrid]

Comment: Many thanks! I made one change to your code, which was pass the event object from onChange to the handleConfirmChange() function as a second argument, I was then able to do confirmed: ev.target.checked instead of hard-coding to true. But that was  a minor detail. Thanks again!

Comment: @Rocket04 I have updated the code to pass the row as param and update the `confirmed` property.